# Do I need to change the version when I modify an external library?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I added a new field in a class which is in an external library. Do I need to change the  `<version>1.0.0</version>` or  `<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>` in the pom?

Comment: .... version or modelVersion of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Never* change `<modelVersion>`.

if you patch an external library, change the version number to something like `1.0.0-patched`.